# Getting Caller IP in WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two projects hosted in IIS. First is GUI second WebServices.
I have to get a caller IP address in WebServices (WebMethod).

I Tried:

```
Context.Request.UserHostAddress
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
Context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

First two return::1
third return null.

When I try them in GUI code behind right before calling WebMethot I get correct IP addresses.
How can I get a Caller IP address in WebMethod?

I use ASP Net 4.0

-- Edit

What I mean is that both projects are hosted on server.

Let's say servers IP is 192.168.0.2.
My IP is 192.168.0.3.

I'am opening webbrowser and type http://192.168.0.2/GUI. And after I click a button, on code behind Context.Request.UserHostAddress == 192.168.0.3 which is correct.

Button calls WebMethod on the same server http://192.168.0.2/services/service.asmx and there Context.Request.UserHostAddress == ::1 I think it is correct because GUI is hosted on the same server that services are.

My question is how can I get my IP (192.168.0.3) insted ::1.

I tried Context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] but it is empty.

Comment: ::1 is the ipv6 localhost equivalent. If both apps are running on the same machine, then this makes sense. What IP were you expecting to see?

Comment: Yes I know that. But they are hosted on server and I would like to see my onw IP. Because I open the browser and I perform action on GUI which calls WebMethod. GUI see my onw IP but WebMethod does not.

Comment: What do you mean "they are hosted on server"? When you're looking at the results, are both running on the server? Or are both running on your machine? Or is one running on the server and the other running on your machine?

Comment: Hope my edit helped

Comment: You say you tried checking a header, but you never say you actually set that header.